# Error: stack/package openni-tracker not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 lts. When i tried to launch openni-tracker i got the following error message:

[rospack] Error: stack/package openni-tracker not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58708/error:-stack/package-openni-tracker-not-found/) by [ashcoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4480/ashcoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it is not "minus" but "underscore", try with: rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1